# Mesh breaks when smooth modifier is applied

Tags: mesh, modifiers, smooth

I have a model of a teddy bear initially created in another software and imported to Blender as an FBX file.
It has a triangulated mesh, which is not smooth to the level I wish it to be.
When applying smooth modifier, the mesh breaks apart (see image).
I have tried removing duplicates/merging vertices, but it did not help.

I could find anyone asking about the similar issue, so I would be grateful for your help.
[image: Broken mesh of a teddy bear]

Comment: Hello, could you please share the object (the head only)? Read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: In the mesh properties, navigate to the normals panel and check if there are any custom split normals. If there are, remove them

Answer (score 1):

From the way the triangles are separating, it looks as though you should try  adding a weld modifier before the smooth modifier.